# Custom panel layout doesn't work as expected when animating (WPF)

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls

I've got a custom (and getting complex) `TabControl`.  It's a gathering of many sources, plus my own wanted features.  In it is a custom `Panel` to show the headers of the TabControl.  Its features are to compress the size of the `TabItems` until they reached their minimum, and then activates scrolling features (in the Panel, again).  There is also another custom panel to hold a single button, that renders on the right of the `TabItems` (it's a "new tab" button).

It all works great, until I try to animate the scrolling.

Here are some relevant snippets :

In the CustomTabPanel (C#, overriding `Panel` and implementing `IScrollInfo`):

```
private readonly TranslateTransform _translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();

public void LineLeft()
{
    FirstVisibleIndex++;

    var offset = HorizontalOffset + _childRects[0].Width;
    if (offset < 0 || _viewPort.Width >= _extent.Width)
        offset = 0;
    else
    {
        if (offset + _viewPort.Width > _extent.Width)
            offset = _extent.Width - _viewPort.Width;
    }

    _offset.X = offset;
    if (_scrollOwner != null)
        _scrollOwner.InvalidateScrollInfo();

    //Animate the new offset
    var aScrollAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(_translateTransform.X, -offset,
                                           new Duration(this.AnimationTimeSpan), FillBehavior.HoldEnd) { AccelerationRatio = 0.5, DecelerationRatio = 0.5 };
    aScrollAnimation.Completed += ScrollAnimationCompleted;

    _translateTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, aScrollAnimation , HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);

    //End of animation

    // These lines are the only ones needed if we remove the animation
    //_translateTransform.X = -offset;
    //InvalidateMeasure();
}


void ScrollAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

the `_translateTransform` is initialized in the constructor :

```
    base.RenderTransform = _translateTransform;
```

Again, everything is fine if I remove the animation part and just replace it with the commented out lines at the end.

I must also point out that the problem is NOT with the animation itself.  That part works out well.  The problem is about when I remove some tab items : all the layout then screws up.  The TranslateTransformation seems to hold on some wrong value, or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.  As it's often the case, I kept working on the thing, and...  answered myself.

Could still be useful for other people, so here was the catch.  In the line :

```
var aScrollAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(_translateTransform.X, -offset, new Duration(this.AnimationTimeSpan), FillBehavior.HoldEnd)
    { AccelerationRatio = 0.5, DecelerationRatio = 0.5 };
```

the `FillBehavior` should have been `FillBehavior.Stop`.

As easy as that!